# PercentEncoding makes unexpected result if URL including Korean

Tags: swift, urlencode, cjk

Here is an unexpected percent encoding result for URLs, including Korean.

Original URL :

`https://example.url/to/path#name=한글&example=example`

Do the following :

`"\(Original URL).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)"`

Expectation :

`https://example.url/to/path#name=%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80&example=example`

Happened :

`https://example.url/to/path%23name=%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80&example=example`

The percentEncoding changes # in the middle of the URL to %23. 
 It leads unexpected domain and makes a 404 error.

Also It doesn't change when the URL does not contain Korean
(ex: `https://example.url/to/path#name=hangle&example=example`).

How can I approach this problem? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why does the URL use `#` instead of `?` to start the query parameters portion? The `#` is for a fragment, not query parameters.

Comment: You may want to consider using `URLComponents` for building a URL.

Comment: Just split the URL first then do all of setup then combine into full URL later

Comment: Ah The URL was not made from me, I received a bug report that website doesn't open properly.

Comment: to my in-app Safari, when clicks the link on UITextView.